# Compatability of Hive, Hbase and Hadoop 2.5.1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I have Hadoop 2.5.1 installed on three nodes (1 master, 2 slave nodes) and I want to know the version compatibility of HBase and Hive?

Also, are any alternatives for this Hadoop+Hbase+Hive integration or any guides explaining the installation of Hadoop 2.5.1 with compatible HBase and Hive ?

Currently I am trying with Apache Ambari for the above integration and its still ongoing.

Environment:
Jdk version: 1.7.0_67

RHEL 5

64 bit architecture

Any leads will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With hadoop 2.5.1 supported versions are:

- HBase-0.98.x (Support for Hadoop 1.1+ is deprecated.)
- HBase-1.0.x (Hadoop 1.x is NOT supported)
- HBase-1.1.x
- HBase-1.2.x

Here is the link : http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Warning: only hive 1.2.1 can work with Hbase 2.x.